# How to use the confusion matrix module in NLTK?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I followed the NLTK book in using the confusion matrix but the confusionmatrix looks very odd.

```
#empirically exam where tagger is making mistakes
test_tags = [tag for sent in brown.sents(categories='editorial')
    for (word, tag) in t2.tag(sent)]
gold_tags = [tag for (word, tag) in brown.tagged_words(categories='editorial')]
print nltk.ConfusionMatrix(gold_tags, test_tags)
```

Can anyone explain how to use the confusion matrix?

Comment: Why do you think you're making a mistake? What does *"looks very odd"* mean? What inputs do you give, what outputs do you get and what were you expecting?

Comment: Your question is more confusing than ``ConfusionMatrix``! How on earth it's possible to answer a question like this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Firstly, I assume that you got the code from old `NLTK`'s chapter 05: https://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch05.py, particularly you're look at this section: http://pastebin.com/EC8fFqLU

Now, let's look at the confusion matrix in `NLTK`, try:

```
from nltk.metrics import ConfusionMatrix
ref  = 'DET NN VB DET JJ NN NN IN DET NN'.split()
tagged = 'DET VB VB DET NN NN NN IN DET NN'.split()
cm = ConfusionMatrix(ref, tagged)
print cm
```

[out]:

```
    | D         |
    | E I J N V |
    | T N J N B |
----+-----------+
DET |<3>. . . . |
 IN | .<1>. . . |
 JJ | . .<.>1 . |
 NN | . . .<3>1 |
 VB | . . . .<1>|
----+-----------+
(row = reference; col = test)
```

The numbers embedded in `<>` are the true positives (tp). And from the example above, you see that one of the `JJ` from reference was wrongly tagged as `NN` from the tagged output. For that instance, it counts as one false positive for `NN` and one false negative for `JJ`.

To access the confusion matrix (for calculating precision/recall/fscore), you can access the false negatives, false positives and true positives by:

```
labels = set('DET NN VB IN JJ'.split())

true_positives = Counter()
false_negatives = Counter()
false_positives = Counter()

for i in labels:
    for j in labels:
        if i == j:
            true_positives[i] += cm[i,j]
        else:
            false_negatives[i] += cm[i,j]
            false_positives[j] += cm[i,j]

print "TP:", sum(true_positives.values()), true_positives
print "FN:", sum(false_negatives.values()), false_negatives
print "FP:", sum(false_positives.values()), false_positives
```

[out]:

```
TP: 8 Counter({'DET': 3, 'NN': 3, 'VB': 1, 'IN': 1, 'JJ': 0})
FN: 2 Counter({'NN': 1, 'JJ': 1, 'VB': 0, 'DET': 0, 'IN': 0})
FP: 2 Counter({'VB': 1, 'NN': 1, 'DET': 0, 'JJ': 0, 'IN': 0})
```

To calculate Fscore per label:

```
for i in sorted(labels):
    if true_positives[i] == 0:
        fscore = 0
    else:
        precision = true_positives[i] / float(true_positives[i]+false_positives[i])
        recall = true_positives[i] / float(true_positives[i]+false_negatives[i])
        fscore = 2 * (precision * recall) / float(precision + recall)
    print i, fscore
```

[out]:

```
DET 1.0
IN 1.0
JJ 0
NN 0.75
VB 0.666666666667
```

I hope the above will de-confuse the confusion matrix usage in `NLTK`, here's the full code for the example above:

```
from collections import Counter
from nltk.metrics import ConfusionMatrix

ref  = 'DET NN VB DET JJ NN NN IN DET NN'.split()
tagged = 'DET VB VB DET NN NN NN IN DET NN'.split()
cm = ConfusionMatrix(ref, tagged)

print cm

labels = set('DET NN VB IN JJ'.split())

true_positives = Counter()
false_negatives = Counter()
false_positives = Counter()

for i in labels:
    for j in labels:
        if i == j:
            true_positives[i] += cm[i,j]
        else:
            false_negatives[i] += cm[i,j]
            false_positives[j] += cm[i,j]

print "TP:", sum(true_positives.values()), true_positives
print "FN:", sum(false_negatives.values()), false_negatives
print "FP:", sum(false_positives.values()), false_positives
print 

for i in sorted(labels):
    if true_positives[i] == 0:
        fscore = 0
    else:
        precision = true_positives[i] / float(true_positives[i]+false_positives[i])
        recall = true_positives[i] / float(true_positives[i]+false_negatives[i])
        fscore = 2 * (precision * recall) / float(precision + recall)
    print i, fscore
```

Comment: This is really helpful! Thanks so much. How did you get your confusion matrix to print so neatly? when I type in print cm, I get something really ugly.

Comment: it's because the matrix i show is small, so it looks neat, if not it's rather ugly hahaha.

Comment: haha ic. do you know how to deal with large confusion matrices to make them more legible?

Answer (score 1):

This is a real case of a text classifier, 
works with sklearn and NLTK

```
from collections import defaultdict
refsets = defaultdict(set)
testsets = defaultdict(set)
labels = []
tests = []
for i, (feats, label) in enumerate(testset):
    refsets[label].add(i)
    observed = classifier.classify(feats)
    testsets[observed].add(i)
    labels.append(label)
    tests.append(observed)

print(metrics.confusion_matrix(labels, tests))
print(nltk.ConfusionMatrix(labels, tests))

    |   n   p |
    |   e   o |
    |   g   s |
----+---------+
neg |<228> 22 |
pos |  18<232>|
----+---------+
   (row = reference; col = test)

    [[228  22]
     [ 18 232]]
```