# python tabulating confusion matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tabular, confusion-matrix

In my sklearn logistic regression model, I obtained a confusion matrix using `metrics.confusion_matrix` command.  The array looks like this

```
array([[51,  0],
   [26,  0]])
```

Ignoring the fact that the model did pretty bad, I am trying to understand what is the best way to tabulate this matrix in pretty way

I am trying to use [tabulate package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) and this code partially works for me

```
print tabulate(cm,headers=['Pred True', 'Pred False'])
```

as it gives output

```
  Pred True    Pred False
-----------  ------------
     51             0
     26             0
```

**EDIT**

TO insert row names, I realized inserting elements rather than zip would help

```
cm_list=cm.tolist()
cm_list[0].insert(0,'Real True')
cm_list[1].insert(0,'Real False')
print tabulate(cm_list,headers=['Real/Pred','Pred True', 'Pred False'])
```

as it gives

```
Real/Pred      Pred True    Pred False
-----------  -----------  ------------
Real True             51             0
Real False            26             0
```

However, would still like to know if there is a quicker or alternate way of beautifying confusion matrix. (I found some plotting examples on web but I do not need that)

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered creating a figure rather than a table? Adapting some code from a [scikit-learn example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html) you can get a decent looking figure which shows what you want.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, target_names, title='Confusion matrix', cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
    plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()
    tick_marks = np.arange(len(target_names))
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, target_names, rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks, target_names)
    plt.tight_layout()

    width, height = cm.shape

    for x in xrange(width):
        for y in xrange(height):
            plt.annotate(str(cm[x][y]), xy=(y, x), 
                        horizontalalignment='center',
                        verticalalignment='center')
    plt.ylabel('True label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label')

cm = np.array([[13,  0,  0],[ 0, 10,  6],[ 0,  0,  9]])
plot_confusion_matrix(cm, ['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

[image: matplotlib confusion matrix plot]

Comment: Looks good and yes I did consider that but I just thought that is an overkill for my need. However, your plot is much cleaner and the face that numbers appear in the boxes makes it an attractive alternative

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't realise you'd looked at this. I always prefer a visual representation, it scales much better than a table which can be overwhelming with large number of labels.

Answer (score 2):

The `nltk` library includes a confusion matrix that is simple to use and produces a nicer output than scikit-learn:

```
from nltk import ConfusionMatrix
print(ConfusionMatrix(list(y_true_values), list(y_predicted_values)))
```

You can see an example of the output [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23715286/1636598). Note that I wrapped `y_true_values` and `y_predicted_values` in the `list()` function because `ConfusionMatrix` expects Python lists rather than the NumPy arrays output by scikit-learn.

Alternatively, the `mlxtend` library includes a function to plot a confusion matrix, documented [here](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/evaluate/confusion_matrix/).

Answer (score 1):

Using `pandas` and `tabulate` you can do it like this (`pandas` uses `tabulate` under the hood to generate markdown):

```
>> y_true = ['cat', 'dog', 'cat']
>> y_pred = ['cat', 'cat', 'cat']
>> print(pd.DataFrame(confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels=labels), columns=labels, index=labels).to_markdown())
|     |   cat |   dog |
|:----|------:|------:|
| cat |     2 |     0 |
| dog |     1 |     0 |
```