# How can I have a good visualization of the confusion matrix?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, visualization, confusion-matrix

I'm working on a classification problem and I wanted to visualize confusion matrix. But i have a problem is that the number are not in the middle. Here you can see the code :

```
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(X_train,Y_train)
y_test_pred = lr.predict(X_test)
print("The accuracy of the logistic regression : ",(accuracy_score(y_test_pred,Y_test)*100), "%")

confusion_matrix = pd.crosstab(Y_test, y_test_pred, rownames=['Actual'], colnames=['Predicted'])
cm = confusion_matrix.astype('float') / confusion_matrix.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]

# Visualization
plt.figure 
plt.title('Logistic Regression')
sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True)
plt.show()
```

The output is something like that :
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yhgX.png)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python tabulating confusion matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35585069/python-tabulating-confusion-matrix)

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cm=confusion_matrix(y,y_pred)
plt.matshow(cm,cmap=plt.cm.Greens)
plt.colorbar() 
plt.show()
```

plt.matshow() can help.

Add how to put the number in the middle. 
Key words: horizontalalignment, verticalalignment can locate the position of annotation.

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.matshow(cm,cmap=plt.cm.Greens)  # plot matrix    
    plt.colorbar() 

    for i in range(len(cm)):
        for j in range(len(cm)):
            plt.annotate(cm[i,j],xy=(j,i),horizontalalignment='center',verticalalignment='center',size=15,color='orange')
```

Comment: the problem is not how to visualizate confuxion matrix, if you see the image of the output you'll see that when I visualizate my confuxion matrix, the number are not in the middle so I can't see them clearly...I want to know where is the problem ?

Comment: Got it. please find my edited answer. Hope it will help.

Comment: You can also find similar solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35585069/python-tabulating-confusion-matrix

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. In my case, I only uninstall the existing version of matplotlib and reinstall it with version 3.0.0. It works for me! (I know it's not a permanent solution, though).

First:

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
```

And then:

```
pip install matplotlib==3.0
```

Hope it helps.