# Confusion Matrix - Testing Sentiment Analysis Model

Tags: scikit-learn, nltk, sentiment-analysis, confusion-matrix

I am testing a Sentiment Analysis model using NLTK. I need to add a Confusion Matrix to the classifier results and if possible also Precision, Recall and F-Measure values. I have only accuracy so far. Movie_reviews data has pos and neg labels. However to train the classifier I am using "featuresets" that has a different format from the usual (sentence, label) structure. I am not sure if I can use confusion_matrix from sklearn, after training the classifier by "featuresets"

```
import nltk
import random
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews

documents = [(list(movie_reviews.words(fileid)), category)
             for category in movie_reviews.categories()
             for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category)]

random.shuffle(documents)

all_words = []

for w in movie_reviews.words():
    all_words.append(w.lower())

all_words = nltk.FreqDist(all_words)

word_features = list(all_words.keys())[:3000]

def find_features(document):
    words = set(document)
    features = {}
    for w in word_features:
        features[w] = (w in words)

    return features


featuresets = [(find_features(rev), category) for (rev, category) in documents]

training_set = featuresets[:1900]
testing_set =  featuresets[1900:]


classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)


print("Naive Bayes Algo accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, testing_set))*100)
```

Comment: http://streamhacker.com/2010/05/17/text-classification-sentiment-analysis-precision-recall/

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704361/how-to-use-the-confusion-matrix-module-in-nltk-python ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you can classify all test values and store predicted outcomes and gold results in a list.

Then, you can use **nltk.ConfusionMatrix**.

```
test_result = []
gold_result = []

for i in range(len(testing_set)):
    test_result.append(classifier.classify(testing_set[i][0]))
    gold_result.append(testing_set[i][1])
```

Now, You can calculate different metrics.

```
CM = nltk.ConfusionMatrix(gold_result, test_result)
print(CM)

print("Naive Bayes Algo accuracy percent:"+str((nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, testing_set))*100)+"\n")

labels = {'pos', 'neg'}

from collections import Counter
TP, FN, FP = Counter(), Counter(), Counter()
for i in labels:
    for j in labels:
        if i == j:
            TP[i] += int(CM[i,j])
        else:
            FN[i] += int(CM[i,j])
            FP[j] += int(CM[i,j])

print("label\tprecision\trecall\tf_measure")
for label in sorted(labels):
    precision, recall = 0, 0
    if TP[label] == 0:
        f_measure = 0
    else:
        precision = float(TP[label]) / (TP[label]+FP[label])
        recall = float(TP[label]) / (TP[label]+FN[label])
        f_measure = float(2) * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)
    print(label+"\t"+str(precision)+"\t"+str(recall)+"\t"+str(f_measure))
```

You can check - how to calculate **precision and recall** [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall#Definition_.28classification_context.29).

You can also use : **sklearn.metrics** for these calculations using gold_result and test_result values.

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix   

print '\nClasification report:\n', classification_report(gold_result, test_result)
print '\nConfussion matrix:\n',confusion_matrix(gold_result, test_result)
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: @RAVI, I don't get how you get the predicted outcomes. It seems to me you store all the classified test values in the list (test_result) and the reference ones to the list (gold_result). Where are the predicted outcomes there?

Comment: @RAVI, the link you provided for nltk.metrics says I have to build 2 sets for each classification label. I guess I have to modify all the code to do this, right?

Comment: test_result values are predicted outcomes. you can see that test_result is classifer.classify()

Comment: for other metrics(precision, recall, f-measure). I have to change my code, building 2 sets for each classification label or there is a better way?

Comment: @RAVI, yes confusion_matrix of nltk much nicer and classification_report of sklearn straight forward and it works simply with 2 params (test_result, gold_result). However sklearn precision_score still with 2 params gave me a ValueError: pos_label=1 is not a valid label: array(['pos', 'neg'] that I could fix with lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer(). But classification_report works so great!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118153/discussion-between-ravi-and-ganesa75).

Comment: @RAVI, can you share how to add cross validation and modify params for the 7 algos I have listed to the chat? as my precision and recall are quite low