# How Can I Use Confusion Matrix With Naive Bayes in Python?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I want to classify many sentences with Naive Bayes classifier with 5 categories and I can do, but I can not create a confusion matrix. I researched much but I could not find. These are my code, please teach me how to create a confusion matrix over these code:

```
nb_classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainData)
print(accuracy(nb_classifier, testData))
#Output is 0.8152876648699048

print(nb_classifier.labels())
#Output is ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4', 'cat5']
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704361/how-to-use-the-confusion-matrix-module-in-nltk/23715286 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be worth using the following way to build the classifier. The confusion matrix is also included.

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB # or any other NB model
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

nb_classifier = MultinomialNB()

nb_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = nb_classifier.predict(X_test)

acc_score = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
conf_mat = confusion_matrix(
        y_test, y_pred, labels = ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4', 'cat5'])

print(acc_score)
print(conf_mat)
```

Comment: Why we have to use x_train and y_train, can't they be in same variable?

Comment: The labels you want to predict belong to your dependent variable, the rest of the data is comprised of the independent variables. The classifiers analyse the independent variables and try to predict the labels in the dependent variable. If you include the dependent variable in X the classifiers may completely ignore all other variables and decide that the only variable that is important is the variable that you are trying to predict. So you will end up comparing the dependent variable with itself.

Comment: I hope you have realised that in order to calculate the confusion matrix you need to pass to the function a set of known labels y_test and a set of predicted labels y_pred. The latter are calculated when you invoke the .predict() method of the classifier.

Comment: this gives me an error that "float() can be a string or int, not a dict. My data is like so [{'look':true,'a':true,'bird':true},'cat1']. What should I do?

Comment: Pass y_test and y_pred in the form of a list of strings to confusion_matrix. For, example if you have a list of articles and wanted to build a classifier which predicts the city that the article is about your y data is a list of cities. Then the classifier puts out the predicted city labels and you compare the two lists. If the y labels contained only five cities, then the lists could be ['London', 'Paris', 'Berlin', 'Madrid', 'Stockholm'] or any other cities you have in the training and test sets.

Comment: but error happens here nb_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train). what should be these form?

Comment: I think you have skipped a few vital steps in building a classifier. Please read about data preprocessing, train_test_split and CountVectorizer in order to understand that how to prepare the required X_train, X_train, y_train and y_test. If you can't solve the problem then please post a new question.